# How can you prove that a matrix doesn't have an inverse without using determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How can you prove that a matrix doesn't have an inverse without using determinants?

Just as a general method or technique, how do you go about doing this?

Comment: One strategy is to use Gaussian elimination: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination. A matrix is invertible iff its row reduced form is the identity matrix.

Comment: You can find it's eigenvalues, a matrix is not invertible if any of it's eigenvalues are zero. It's best to look up the invertible matrix theorem. Another condition is if the nullspace is nontrivial. Though these are all equivalent

Comment: [The invertible matrix theorem on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem): For a square $n\times n$ matrix $A$, the following are equivalent statements: There is a $B$ for which $AB=I$, There is a $B$ for which $BA=I$, the determinant of $A$ is nonzero, the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, the image of $A$ is $\Bbb R^n$, and the list goes on... checking any one of those properties and seeing it is true implies all of the properties in the list are true and vice versa.

Comment: Surely @KennyWong 's suggestion is the cheapest and most efficient way to proceed, and it requires absolutely no thought.

Comment: A square $A$ is invertible iff no vector $v\ne 0$ satisfies $Av=0$ (which can be written as simultaneous equations; you can check whether there's a nonzero solution).

Comment: For future reference, please include the problem statement in the body of your Question, not only in the title.  While this particular problem fits in the title (and I'm not suggesting the title be edited), having it in the body of the Question gives Readers an easier task of parsing out what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, if it is not square, then it is not invertible in the sense of having a left and right inverse.

If the matrix is square, then the columns must be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

One trick that works sometimes is to explicitly exhibit a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av$ is 0. Another is to notice a simple linear dependence between some rows or some columns.